# How to get each tkinter Entry's unique value from loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a hangman game which produces a random amount of entries. Problem is, I can't get the unique value of each entry.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
from tkinter import *
import random


root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')

color = 'blue'

a1 = Canvas(root, height = 500, width = 500, bg = color)
a1.pack()

#Variable Declaration
var = StringVar()
x = ''

words = ['penguin','wolves','skyscraper','dinosaur','time travel']
lists = {}

def Enter():
    for i in lists:print(lists[i])



x = 'entry'

a=150
b=350
for i in range(len(random.choice(words))):
    lists[f'entry{i}'] = Entry(textvariable = StringVar(),width =3, font = 'tahoma',justify=CENTER).place(x=a,y=b)
    a+=30


b1 = Button(root, text = "Enter",command=Enter)
b1.place(x=225,y=400)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: All the values in dictionary `lists` should be None because they are assigned to the result of `place()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you must do is separate the creation of the widget from the layout of the widget. In python, `x().y()` returns the value of `y()`, so `Entry(...).place(...)` returns the value of `place(...)` and `place(...)` always returns `None`.

The second thing I would do is not use `f'entry{i}'` for the index into your lists. It will work, but it's more cumbersome than it needs to be.

```
for i in range(len(random.choice(words))):
    lists[i] = Entry(textvariable = StringVar(),width =3, font = 'tahoma',justify=CENTER)
    lists[i].place(x=a,y=b)
    a+=30
```

The above lets you easily reference any entry widget with something like `lists[0]`, `lists[1]`, etc.

Finally, in your `Enter` method (which should be named `enter` according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines), you can directly loop over the entries without using the index at all:

```
def Enter():
    for index, entry in lists.items():
        value = entry.get()
        print(value)
```

Comment: Appreciated sir, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would advice the make 1 input field for text and split the letter later.
A string in python can be accessed like a list, you have len(string) and string[3] gives the 4 letter ect.